# UPW webrtc_PeerCC to PeerCC-browser

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, webrtc, hololens

I would like to do video call from UWP PeerCC app to Browser or from HoloLens (HL) peerCC (unity) to browser.
With PeerCC-browser example I am able to call successfully from web-browser to web-browser but when I try to call from UWP peerCC sample (windows app), I am not able to see the remote stream at browser.

- browser --> browser : works fine
- browser --> uwp peerCC : at peercc i can see local and remote video but on browser side it just show local video.
- HL --> browser same result.

It also did not show any error.

I am using this https://github.com/OpticalTone/PeerCC-Browser code sample for browser side.

I have tried to debug it with some log messages, I noticed that the 
ontrack()
function {the code is below} called but the stream object has zero length.

```
//display remote track in the video element
    pc.ontrack = function(event) {
      videoRenderer = document.getElementById("rtcRenderer");
        videoRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      console.log("Remote track resceved");
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    };
    updateServerStatus();
  }
```

any idea what could be the potential problem will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: And what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: @MindSwipe PeerCC is a WebRTC app for UWP, written in C# I am sending the stream from PeerCC UWP app to Browser [peer-1 written in C#, peer-2 written in Javascript]